# java, for statement: access incremented value outside the loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < Tri.length; i++)
    for(int v = 1; v < Tri.length; v++)
    {
        boolean plz = Tri[i].compareColors(Tri[v]);
        if (v == i)
            continue;
        if (plz == true)
            System.out.println("Triangle " + i + " is equal to  Triangle " + v + " " + plz);
    }
```

i need to use the value of i outside of the loop.Currently the print statement is being looped 21 X more than what i need. Is there any way i can access  'i' with having all my code in a for loop

Comment: I don't know what "the print statement is being looped 21x more ..." has to do with accessing the "i" variable outside of the loop.

Comment: Keep in mind that outside of the loop, at best you'll have the last value that `i` was inside the loop.

Comment: For the future, you don't need to use `if(plz == true)` - using `if(plz)` will do the same thing

Comment: Just declare `var i;` outside of `for` loop and replace 'var i=0` to `i=0` in for loop

Answer (score 0):

To access `i` outside of the loop, change the first line to this:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < Tri.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while loop`

```
int i = 0;
int v = 1;
while (i < Tri.length) {
 while (v < Tri.length) {
   boolean plz= Tri[i].compareColors(Tri[v]);
            if(v==i)
            continue;
            if(plz == true )
                System.out.println("Triangle " + i + " is equal to  Triangle "+ v+ " "+  plz);
  v++;
 }
 i++;
}
```